# How to remove specific repeated columns from pandas dataframe leaving only one instance

Tags: pandas

I know the above-mentioned might probably be a simple task, but it has already taken me a lot of hours without any success. I have also search the web with no success thus far. So, I have the following dataframe:

[image]

And, I am looking for the below desired outcome:

[image]

I used the following line of code:

```
# drop repeat columns leaving the first instance only:
 df_combo = df_combo.drop_duplicates(['Asgn Carr Cd','Fiscal Month'], keep='first')
```

However, this does not accomplish my desired outcome. Thank you in advance for your help/suggestiona.

Comment: It is always recommended to post your example in text format in your post NOT in images/links/or some other sites it will make people's life easy who are trying to help, kindly do edit your post and do let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `groupby` with `first`

```
df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `np.unique` to get one index per unique column name, then slice:

```
import numpy as np

df.iloc[:, np.unique(df.columns, return_index=True)[1]]
```